# How to check updated object in rspec in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

We use rspec and factorygirl to test update in invoice controller. The rspec code is:

```
inv = Factory(:invoice, :paid_out => false)
get 'update', :id => inv.id, :invoice => {:paid_out => true}
```

How to exam values in updated object inv? We tried something like below:

```
inv.paid_out.should == true
```

However the status of inv object is before the update and did not reflect the updated value.

Any thoughts? Thanks so much.

Comment: what if you stringify `true` (ie "true")?

Comment: other option, try: `inv.reload.paid_out.should == true`

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, reload your object to get the updated data.